# Sumar 1 a una cantidad de una base de datos sin un SELECT previo

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo una base de datos donde almaceno las visitas de cada página, y quiero sumar la cantidad de "1" sin tener que hacer un `SELECT` previo.

Quiero evitar esto:

```
SELECT visitas FROM articulos WHERE id = 107

// Imaginemos que esto devuelve que las $visitas actuales son 20

$visitas++;

UPDATE articulos SET visitas = $visitas
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo y que quede más optimizado? Estoy usando **PHP** con **Sentencias Preparadas**

> Nota: El código anterior está incompleto, solo sirve para explicar el
>   problema de una forma más visual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada vez que actualice tomara el valor actual y sumara 1 de esta manera sumas ahí mismo sin necesidad de un contador.

```
UPDATE articulos SET visitas = visitas + 1;
```